# How to produce deployment version of a Vue.js CLI site?

Tags: npm, vue.js

- I have setup a Vue.js CLI project
- I ran `npm run dev` and it runs in my browser at port 8080
- I made some changes to the site
- I typed `npm run build`.
- moved the contents of the `dist` folder under an Apache server
- but I get the error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(Not
>   Found)

**What else do I need to copy here to avoid this error, or what can't it load exactly?**

[image]

Comment: `npm run build` is the command

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question above, i.e. I copied the files from dist and put them under an Apache web server, but they just show a blank page because apparently they can't load something.

Comment: if the index.html and dist directory at the same level of file structure the `src` `attr` should be something like this  `src="/dist/build.js"` otherwise you need to adjust it according to your server infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out:

Because I put the files in a subdirectory, I had to go into the `index.html` file and search and replace `/static` with `static`.

From: `<link href=/static/css/app.fd50d336198a48f4f49d999710298aad.css`

To: `<link href=static/css/app.fd50d336198a48f4f49d999710298aad.css`